# Git hotfixing existing tags/releases?

Tags: git

Suppose I roll a new version to production e.g. 1.0 using git tagging and continue working on master. What happens if I need to hotfix the 1.0 tag? I clone/fetch 1.0 and then add commits to it for the purpose of bug fixing, but isn't tagging simply a marking facility only? when I push my delta 1.0+ commits which branch do they go to?

The same use-case in SVN I would have two separate branches 1.0 and trunk and it is clear that 1.0 can diverge on its own (and then merge to trunk) but in git it is not so clear to me how this works.

Comment: Sorry this is somewhat a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929975/how-do-you-use-tags-in-git-to-manage-software-versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the short answer (that takes some time to read) is to adopt Vincent's [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) model. It works really great as a starting point when first staring out with git. If nothing else it's a good read to understand more about git.

That being said. Here is how I would do it

- checkout the tag and convert it to a branch (if such doesn't already exists)
- make the changes and test them, retag with 1.1 (or similar)
- release
- merge (or cherry-pick if thats your flavour) into master to keep future releases (2.0) also have the bug fixes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if 1.1 will be a different major version? or would you leave some version holes for hotfixes in 1.0? perhaps 1.0.1, 1.0.2, etc.

Comment: So if 1.1 is going to be the next version then your first release would be 1.0.0 with room for 1.0.* patch/bug fixes. Basically on master you're already working on 1.1 so for patches you need one more level of version. Or you name them 1.0-fix.1 if you like that convention (I don't, I would go with 1.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

It is actually quite similar to SVN.

Tags are **permanent** - they are used to identify **releases**. (On Github, this is not just a convention - that is how releases are actually identified and served up.)

For bug fixes to a release, you need to use some kind of branching convention. What kind of branch convention you use is up to you, but a common one is:

```
master    <-- development branch, for the next release
|--1.0       <-- bug fixes to 1.0
```

So create a 1.0 branch starting from the 1.0 tag, and make your bug fixes on that branch, I suggest.

Comment: What if I want to clone 1.0 but including all the bug fixes applied to tag 1.0 so far? what's the common convention for this?

Comment: A Git repository clone includes all the branches of the repository being cloned from. So you clone a repository, not a branch. Of course you start in one branch by default, but you can check out another one. So you just check out version 1.0. If this is not how you want things to be, you could use an opposite convention: use the master branch for bug fixes to the most recent release, and a "next" branch for the next release, or something like that.