# GIT: [Rejected] (would clobber existing tag) Error

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, git-tag

back story:
We are using [GitVersion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) during our build process to rename build with version numbers. We are also following the [GitFlow](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html) process. We had a `hotfix/2.9.1` branch that may have had another branch merged into it, thus causing GitVersion to go from `2.9.1` to `2.9.2`. To fix this, we tagged the `hotfix/2.9.1` branch with  the tag `2.9.1`. During this time work was being done on the hotfix branch. During the release we deleted the tag, merged `hotfix/2.9.1` into `master`, then tagged master with `2.9.1`. We then back-merged master into `develop` and our `release` branches.

We are now seeing issues in our builds:

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888821/git-hotfixing-existing-tags-releases) regarding tags and I am not sure if this would apply. I've tried deleting the tag locally as suggested [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1311), I tried doing a `git fetch --tags` and pushing. This seems to only be happening on our build server (Azure).

**Forgot to mention:**
If I delete the tag in Azure and re-queue a failed build everything works as expected.

Comment: Tags are only for actual releases. Why did you tag something not in `master` in the first place?

Comment: Probably in order to force the build # to the tag even though someone checked in code from another branch that pushed the gitversion to the next rev,  for the QA bold so the testers wouldn't freak out.

Comment: @NilsWerner, this is not normal practice for us. Like Jay stated, it was to force a build version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue the build once with the `Clean` setting turned to `Sources Directory`, that will clear the local repository on the agent and perform a clean clone.

[image]

If you have multiple agents, you may have to do this until all agents have cleared out their workspace folder this way.
See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#clean-build

Comment: I thought I had set it properly, but I must not have saved it ;) This worked!

Comment: @DDiVita, you can accept it as answer :), since it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Reason may be that you delete the original one tag, and created a same name again.

The solution:

```
git fetch --tags -f
```

Forced to refresh the local tag

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69751423)